# Multi-level ordering in Wordpress

Tags: sort

I have a collection of posts and first I want to order them by 'name' in ASC order and then order by 'date' in ASC order. How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple `orderby` with different sort `order` values are possible as of WordPress 4.0, take a look at the codex page for [`WP_Query` - Order - Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). There is an related Make WordPress Core [article](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/) too.

The following example would comply to what you want:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'orderby' => array(
            'name' => 'ASC',
            'date' => 'ASC'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: @user1848902 Please consider accepting this answer as this has clearly answered your question. Just look for the checkmark next to this answer and click it once. For more info, check [help] and visit the [tour] page

Comment: Glad that this has finally made it to core.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Overdue like forever!